# Tiny MCE not displaying throbber / progress animation

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have the following code but the throbber / progress animation is not showing as described in the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#setProgressState).

The image uploads correctly after a few seconds of inactivity then source input and image dimension fields are populated.

How can I get the little animation while the image is uploading?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/<api-key>/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <textarea>
    Welcome to TinyMCE!
  </textarea>

  <script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',

    file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
      
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
        input.onchange = function() {

            var file = this.files[0];

            // Show progress bar
            tinymce.activeEditor.setProgressState(true);

            // Perform file upload
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    callback(json.location);

                    // Hide progress bar
                    tinymce.activeEditor.setProgressState(false);
                } else {
                    console.error(xhr.statusText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
        };
        input.click();
    }
});

</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your problem. You should see the throbber. I tested your code and it works (Firefox 109.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 11). A quick and dirty way to see what the problem is, is to do a hard `exit` right after you display the throbber, like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setProgressState(true);
alert("Hard exit coming up! Hold tight!");
exit();
```

Run the code, then start inspecting the html/css why the throbber doesn't show.
Using you exact code (with added `exit`), it looks like this (after I manually closed the `alert` dialog and the insert file dialog):

[image: Throbber in action]

Long shot: maybe the file picker dialog was covering the throbber, so you didn't see it.

Anyway, now you can maybe investigate some more why you didn't see the throbber. You should find this when looking at the console:

```
<div class="tox-throbber" aria-busy="true">
    <div aria-label="Loading..." tabindex="0" class="tox-throbber__busy-spinner">
        <div class="tox-spinner">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm trying checking this and will update you shortly.

Comment: You're 100% correct. The throbber is showing but it's behind the file picker dialog. Which kind of defeats the purpose but I guess that's just how TinyMCE works.